# Does anyone that has worked with The Weather Channel API know if it allows hour by hour forecasts?

Tags: api, weather, weather-api

You can access hourly forecasts from their site, but as far as I've read the Data Forecast request on their API only gives daily forecasts, I'm currently working with the Weather Underground API, but I'd like to know if I can do this with TWC before paying the subscription. I already e-mailed them but got no answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Weather Channel API *is* the Weather Underground API. Take a look at the "Weather API" link at the bottom of the weather.com homepage. It's `http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/?ref=twc`

If you want a free weather API, and you're US-centric, you can look at the [weather.gov SOAP Web Service](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/)